# creating a left-side sidebar in word press

Tags: menus

I would like to know how to create a side bar on the left-side.I have a site containing a sidebar in the right side.I need a sidebar in the left side too. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

1. Register a sidebar in your functions.php using [register_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).
2. Put some widgets in your sidebar from the dashboard (Appearance/Widgets).
3. Show the sidebar on specific pages on your website by using [dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) in your php code. Or you can create a sidebar-{your-sidebar-id}.php file and use [get_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) to show the sidebar wherever you want.
4. Use CSS / HTML to style your sidebar to appear on the left.

A working example:

**functions.php**

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'sidebar-left',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="sidebar-box">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>'
    ));
```

**sidebar-left.php**

```
<div id="sidebar-left">
    <?php if ( function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') ) dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-left');?>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
#sidebar-left { float: left; width: 300px; }
// modify to your needs.
```

// Example to show sidebar on the homepage
**index.php**

```
<?php get_header();?>
// your code
// more of your  code
<?php get_sidebar('left');?>
<?php get_footer();?>
```